# How to implement a light pub-sub service on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, publish-subscribe, task-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

During his Google I/O 2009 "Offline processing on App Engine: A look ahead" presentation ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3TuRs9ANhs), [slides](http://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/Th_1045_Offline_Processing_On_App_Engine_A_Look_Ahead.pdf)), Brett Slatkin presents the Task Queue service.

He states that

> *Pub-sub systems maximize transactions, decoupling:*
>
> - *Large numbers of small transactions per second*
> - *One-to-many fan-out with changing receivers*
> - *Guaranteed ordering, filtering, two-phase commit*

And specifically emphasises

> *Our new API implements queueing, not pub-sub*

---

I'm interested in only a subset of those functionalities:

- One-to-many fan-out with <del>changing</del> selected/fixed internal receiver handlers
- <del>Guaranteed ordering</del>, filtering, two-phase commit

Targeted goal would be to ease publishing of notifications/messages between different modules of the same web application. Sample usage scenarios cases would be:

- Making the payment module aware of receivals of bills.
- Making a user able to track changes of a particular domain object he has decided to follow/star.

What would be the correct way to implement these on top of the Task Queue service ?

Comment: His 2010 talk is good, and on this topic, as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSDC_TU7rtc

Answer (score 6):

Consider using [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs). It's the externalized version of the internal Pub/Sub technology, which has been used extensively within google for about 7 years and proven to be scalable and robust. As of today it's still beta, but we're going to GA soon (in few months).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example implementation of PubSubHubbub from Google that runs on AppEngine](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/source/browse/trunk/hub/). You can have a look at how they do it or remove code until it fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Even if some parts of PSHB indeed rely on the Task Queue service, I wouldn't call it a "light" solution ;-). I've edited my question to try and clarify my request (eg. in-app notification mechanism).